# Change color of each individual mod on an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I am making a modded client for a game called Minecraft. My array list will display the mods you have on in the top left of the screen. How do I change the colors of each individual mod? Ex. KillAura will be green and ChestFinder will be red. Thanks

```
//Arraylist GUI

        if(Camb.killaura){
            if(!arraygui.contains("KillAura")){
                arraygui.add("KillAura");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("KillAura")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("KillAura"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.chestfinder){
            if(!arraygui.contains("ChestFinder")){
                arraygui.add("ChestFinder");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("ChestFinder")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("ChestFinder"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.fullbright){
            if(!arraygui.contains("FullBright")){
                arraygui.add("FullBright");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("FullBright")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("FullBright"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.tracers){
            if(!arraygui.contains("Tracers")){
                arraygui.add("Tracers");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("Tracers")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("Tracers"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.autowalk){
            if(!arraygui.contains("AutoWalk")){
                arraygui.add("AutoWalk");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("AutoWalk")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("AutoWalk"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.noweather){
            if(!arraygui.contains("NoWeather")){
                arraygui.add("NoWeather");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("NoWeather")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("NoWeather"));
            }
        }

        if(Camb.sneak){
            if(!arraygui.contains("Sneak")){
                arraygui.add("Sneak");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("Sneak")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("Sneak"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.nocheat){
            if(!arraygui.contains("NoCheat")){
                arraygui.add("NoCheat");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("NoCheat")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("NoCheat"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.nofall){
            if(!arraygui.contains("NoFall")){
                arraygui.add("NoFall");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("NoFall")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("NoFall"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.xray){
            if(!arraygui.contains("X-Ray")){
                arraygui.add("X-Ray");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("X-Ray")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("X-Ray"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.speedmine){
            if(!arraygui.contains("Speedy Gonzales")){
                arraygui.add("Speedy Gonzales");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("Speedy Gonzales")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("Speedy Gonzales"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.criticals){
            if(!arraygui.contains("Criticals")){
                arraygui.add("Criticals");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("Criticals")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("Criticals"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.flight){
            if(!arraygui.contains("Flight")){
                arraygui.add("Flight");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("Flight")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("Flight"));
            }
        }
        if(Camb.wallhack){
            if(!arraygui.contains("WallHack")){
                arraygui.add("WallHack");
            }
        }else{
            if(arraygui.contains("WallHack")){
                arraygui.remove(arraygui.indexOf("WallHack"));
            }
        }
int gh = 17;
        for(int guiInt = 0; guiInt < arraygui.size(); guiInt++){

            var8.drawString("" + arraygui.get(guiInt), 5, gh, 0xFF0000);
```

Comment: how are you painting this to the screen? If you are doing this in an overrided paint() method you can call the `g.setColor(Color);` before each line

Comment: @bas Wouldn't that change the color of every active mod?

Comment: if we are talking about text only, then no, they should take care of their own graphics

Comment: @bas By the way, I draw the text to the screen at the last line. var8

Answer (score 1):

If you edit your code like this:

```
for(int guiInt = 0; guiInt < arraygui.size(); guiInt++){
    String curmod = arraygui.get(guiInt);
    var8.setColor(this.getModColor(curmod));
    var8.drawString(curmod, 5, gh, 0xFF0000);
    // rest of your logic
}

/** This method gets your color for the specified mod
  *
  */
private Color getModColor(String mod)
{
    switch (mod)
    {
        case "KillAura": 
            return Color.green;
        case "ChestFinder":
            return Color.red;
    }

    throw new Exception("This mod has no specified color");
}
```

it should set the color you specify in the method `getModColor(String mod)` for each sentence.

Comment: Yes, that is why you need to check the current displayed mod and change the colour (for example with a method).

Comment: How would I do that. Sorry I'm new :/
By the way, multiple can be displayed at once.